# Java interface code error

Tags: java, interface

I can't understand why I'm getting an error on the line indicated below. if there is a specific topic which covers it please provide a line (or an explanation).

```
public interface Button {
  void press();
}
public class Bomb implements Button {
  public void press() {
    System.out.println("Doesn't work");
  }
  void boom() {
    System.out.println("Exploded");
  }
}
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Button redButton = new Bomb();
    redButton.press();
    redButton.boom(); // <-- Error is on this line.
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, what's the error?

Comment: I'm not sure it's just saying line 16 can't run

Comment: If you're using any decent IDE, the compiler error has *got* to give more information than that...

Comment: even the command line compiler will give a lot more information...

Answer (score 5):

```
Button redButton = new Bomb();
```

The interface `Button` does not define a method `boom()`.

The runtime instance may be a `Bomb` (which has `boom()`), but the compiler does not know that (it only sees the compile time type, which is `Button`).

You need to use the interface defined by class `Bomb`:

```
Bomb redButton = new Bomb();
```

Comment: Because there *is* a method `press()` in the interface `Button`.

Comment: Interface have different concept compared to Inheritance (Super class & Sub class). Interface is used when you need several different implementations of the same method name. In the real life opening coke bottle vs opening the door have different ways, so you need same method name which is open() but the way of opening its different in the other hand, when you need same ways with exactly same method name you may use Inheritance. CMIIW.